# Como pasar parámetros a Policie Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy desarrollando control de acceso por `policies` en `Laravel 6`, en donde tengo varias tiendas la cual puede ver y modificarlos (Precio, promocion, etc) un `superusuario` para todas las tiendas, en cada tienda hay un `admin` que puede modificar precios ver y modificar solo los de su tienda, pero si ver en que tiendas esta disponible el producto, es decir solo el listado mas no modificarlos.

```
<div id="ti">
    @foreach($ps->tienda as $t)
        <div id="td{{$t->Codigo}}" style="margin: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
            @can('lprecio') 
                <span class="badge p" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mprecio" onclick="lprecio({{$ps->codigo}},{{$t->Codigo}})"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></span> 
            @endcan 
            ( {{$t->Abreviatura}} ) {{$t->Descripcion}} 
            @can('dtienda') 
                <span class="badge" onclick="removeti({{$ps->codigo}},{{$t->Codigo}})"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
            @endcan
        </div>  
    @endforeach
</div>
```

ya que si le doy acceso a modificar, en el `for`le da acceso para todos, es decir `@can('lprecio')` le da acceso al usuario para listar precio, la cual solo deberia poder unicamente de su tienda, pero si le quito el acceso, no puede ni al suyo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi `policie`

```
public function lprecio(?User $user){
    return $user->isAccess('list-precio');
}
```

solo verifica que tiene acceso, pero no puedo pasar la `tienda` que se esta recorriendo para ver si pertenece a esta para darle acceso

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    //'\App\User' => 'App\Policies\DetalleAdmin',
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    require_once('Acceso/Detalle.php');
}
```

}

**Detalle.php**

```
Gate::define('lprecio', '\App\Policies\DetalleAdmin@lprecio');
```

**DetalleAdmin**

```
public function lprecio(?User $user,$t){        
    return $user->isAccess('list-precio') && $user->idtienda==$t->Codigo;
}
```

El resultado es el problema,no devuelve, ni aunque solo le ponga `return true;` o `return false;`, sale error al retornar cualquier cosa, incluso si retornara directo

```
public function lprecio(?User $user,$t){        
    return true;
}
```

**Llegada**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que sumar un parámetro en la `policy` y pasarlo en el `@can` como un array (aunque con un solo parámetro creo que no hace falta).

```php
public function lprecio (?User $user, $tienda)
{
    // Chequear lo que haga falta con $tienda
    return $user->isAccess('list-precio');
}
```

```
@can('lprecio', [$ps->tienda])
```

Comment: el parámetro llega pero me sale otro error `Too few arguments to function App\Policies\DetalleAdmin::lprecio(), 1 passed`, comprobé todo y si llega, compara pero no devuelve, a que debe eso?

Comment: Cómo y dónde tenés registrada esa policy? Publicá tu `AuthServiceProvider`. Si tira error no debería llegar y si llega no debería tirar error. Probá sin encerrarlo entré corchetes (que no sea un array).

Comment: con o sin corchetes, es el mismo, llega pero no devuelve nada, ni aunque solo le ponga `return true;` o `return false;`, sale error al retornar cualquier cosa